# Why do I get "ClientInputError - exceptionMessage='Server error returned in unknown format' while using Bulk Query

Tags: apex, rest-api, java, bulk-api

I am using Bulk Query, reading one batch at a time, and writing to the standard output. When the records size is small like 100000 records, the job works fine, but when I try to extract records like for example 7 million records (7000000 records), the job aborts with the following exception

Job id is 750A0000004YXlsIAG
[AsyncApiException  exceptionCode='ClientInputError'
 exceptionMessage='Server error returned in unknown format'
]

```
at com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.parseAndThrowException(BulkConnection.java:190)
at com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.doHttpGet(BulkConnection.java:747)
at com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.getBatchInfo(BulkConnection.java:557)
at com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.getBatchInfo(BulkConnection.java:550)
```

Attached is the source code, and the Salesforce Jar files that I use is 
force-partner-api-39.0.0.jar
force-wsc-39.0.0.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar

Thanks for the help

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.sforce.async.*;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;


public class BulkQueryPerformanceObject {

static int finalBatchCount=0;   
static JobInfo job = new JobInfo();
static BulkConnection bulkConnection = null;
BatchInfo[] bListInfo = null;
int numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract = 0;
int numberOfRecordsExtracted = 0;
long startTime = System.nanoTime();


public static void main(String[] args)
  throws AsyncApiException, ConnectionException, IOException {
    BulkQueryPerformanceObject exampleQuery = new BulkQueryPerformanceObject();
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
    bulkConnection = exampleQuery.login();
    bulkConnection.addHeader("Sforce-Enable-PKChunking","chunkSize=10000");
    exampleQuery.doBulkQuery(bulkConnection);
}


public BulkConnection login() {

      String userName = "testing1@ibm.com";
      String passWord = "ibmsalesVInDXaqvHnNEQgqTDIC24AAn";
      String url = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0";
      BulkConnection _bulkConnection = null;
      try {

            ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
            partnerConfig.setUsername(userName);
            partnerConfig.setPassword(passWord);
            partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint(url);
            new PartnerConnection(partnerConfig);
            ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
            config.setSessionId(partnerConfig.getSessionId());
            String soapEndpoint = partnerConfig.getServiceEndpoint();
            String apiVersion = "37.0";
            String restEndpoint = soapEndpoint.substring(0, soapEndpoint.indexOf("Soap/"))
                + "async/" + apiVersion;
            config.setRestEndpoint(restEndpoint);
            config.setCompression(true);
            config.setTraceMessage(false);
            _bulkConnection = new BulkConnection(config);
      } catch (AsyncApiException aae) {
        aae.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
      }
      return _bulkConnection;
    }



public void doBulkQuery(BulkConnection bulkConnection) {

      try {
        job.setObject("PerformanceObject__c");      
        job.setOperation(OperationEnum.query);
        job.setConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyMode.Parallel);
        job.setContentType(ContentType.CSV);

        job = bulkConnection.createJob(job);
        assert job.getId() != null;
        System.out.println("Job id is " + job.getId());


        String query = "Select Id, Name, OwnerId From PerformanceObject__c";
        ByteArrayInputStream bout = new ByteArrayInputStream(query.getBytes()); 
        bulkConnection.createBatchFromStream(job, bout);

        bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();

        while(bListInfo.length < 2)
            bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();

        finalBatchCount++;
        BatchInfo info = bListInfo[finalBatchCount];
        numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract++;

        String[] queryResults = null;

        for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) 
        {
            info = bulkConnection.getBatchInfo(job.getId(), info.getId());

            if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed) 
            {
                QueryResultList list = bulkConnection.getQueryResultList(job.getId(),info.getId());             
                queryResults = list.getResult();
                break;
            } 
            else if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Failed) 
            {
                System.out.println("-------------- failed ----------" + info);                  
                break;
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("-------------- waiting ----------"  + info);               
            }
        }

        if (queryResults != null) 
        {
            for (String resultId : queryResults) 
            {
                InputStream resultStream = bulkConnection.getQueryResultStream(job.getId(), info.getId(), resultId);
                BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resultStream,"UTF8"));
                String lineString = null;
                lineString = lineReader.readLine();
                while((lineString = lineReader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println("lineString : " + lineString);
                    numberOfRecordsExtracted++;
                }
            }
        }               

      } catch (AsyncApiException aae) {
            aae.printStackTrace();
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    while(!getMoreData())
    {}

    System.out.println("Number of batches created with chunkSize 2000 is " + numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract);
    System.out.println("Number of total records extracted is " + numberOfRecordsExtracted);
    System.out.println("Final Total Batch Count is " + finalBatchCount);
    System.out.println("Job state is " + job.getState());
    long finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    long elapsedTime = (finishTime - startTime)/1000000; 
    int seconds = (int)(elapsedTime / 1000) % 60 ;
    int minutes = (int)((elapsedTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
    int hours = (int)((elapsedTime / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    System.out.println("Time for processing is "+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}

public boolean isQueryDone()
{
    try {
        if(finalBatchCount < (bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo().length -1))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            bulkConnection.closeJob(job.getId());
            return true;
        }
    } catch (AsyncApiException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}


public boolean getMoreData() 
{
    try{
    if ( isQueryDone() )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();
        finalBatchCount++;
        BatchInfo info = bListInfo[finalBatchCount];
        numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract++;

        String[] queryResults = null;

        for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) 
        {
            info = bulkConnection.getBatchInfo(job.getId(), info.getId());

            if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed) 
            {
                QueryResultList list = bulkConnection.getQueryResultList(job.getId(),info.getId());             
                queryResults = list.getResult();
                break;
            } 
            else if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Failed) 
            {
                System.out.println("-------------- failed ----------" + info);                  
                break;
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("-------------- waiting ----------"  + info);               
            }
         }

         if (queryResults != null) 
         {
            for (String resultId : queryResults) 
            {
                InputStream resultStream = bulkConnection.getQueryResultStream(job.getId(), info.getId(), resultId);
                BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resultStream,"UTF8"));
                String lineString = null;
                lineReader.readLine();
                while((lineString = lineReader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println("lineString : " + lineString);
                    numberOfRecordsExtracted++;
                }
            }
          } 
    return false;    
    }
    } catch (AsyncApiException aae) {
        aae.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return false; 
    }

public String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line; 
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF8"));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(flag? newLine: "").append(line);
            flag = true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.toString();
}


public static int countLines(String filename)  
{
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));

        byte[] c = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        int readChars = 0;
        boolean empty = true;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            empty = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                if (c[i] == '\n') {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: You can try getBatchInfoList(String jobId, ContentType contentType) API.